# Is there a speed / process improvement when using <?php instead of <?

Tags: php, tags, shortcode

Just curious to know if

```
<?php ?>
```

can increase or improve process speeds and requests as apposed to

```
<? ?>
```

Comment: No, and using <? can cause problems if short open tags aren't enabled

Comment: 3 less letters must be processed a few nanoseconds faster?

Comment: @Dagon - not necessarily, because there's special cases of <?= that need to be "processed" and differentiated from <?; and if you're using an opcode cache such as APC, it's a token that isn't necessarily 3 characters less

Answer (score 1):

Theres no performance impact.

to use `<?` ( or short_tags)  you need it enabled on php.ini

short tags are not deprecated.

also `<?=` which is equal to `<?php echo` is always available since php 5.4

fig-standarts psr-1 also made clear to use only `<?php` or `<?=` for framework codes

This question is a very long and old one about the subject and does have way more information bout it.

[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Thank you for the share, and thank you to everyone for such great answers :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant performance implications in using either one.

How ever short tags `<? ?>` are deprecated and should not be used (except for the short echo tag `<?= ?>`, which is now available by default).

Comment: Ack, deleted what I meant to say . . . I still don't think short tags are deprecated.  Their usage is frowned upon, but the actual <? isn't being phased out.

Answer (score 0):

No. Both constructs are equally slow (it is noticable when used extensively in templates).